# Unable to get Django next parameter in login view

Tags: django

I have a custom login view in a Django (ver 1.8.4) app.
There are times when using the app that the user will get to the login page and the URL will have a **'next'** parameter such as `http://127.0.0.1:8000/login/?next=/search/`,
that I want to capture and process in my login view.

The problem is that I am unable to do so.
I've tried `request.GET.get('next', '')` and `request.POST.get('next', '')` and `request.POST.get('redirect_field_name', request.GET.get('redirect_field_name', ''))`.

They all return an empty string. I've tried `request.path` and `request.get_full_path()` which returns `/login/` without the next parameter. At this point I can't figure out why this isn't working. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Please edit your question and add your custom login view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find previous url from request.META["HTTP_REFERER"] parameter then split that from '?' and get the rest as well.

Comment: That took care of it. Thanks a lot. It was easy once I had that info.